# w3-css empty column doesnt occupy space but in bootstrap it does

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, w3c

Well, you all might be aware about new **w3-css** by w3schools. [W3-css link](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp)
I was doing some handson with **w3-css**, seems something is fishy with their grid columns.

Obviously this gonna be compared with **Bootstrap**.
While in **bootstrap** when you keep any column empty it just occupies the space but this does not happen in **w3-css**.

So **w3-css** is forcing people not to leave their column empty else it will screw  your layout.

*What could be the possible fix for this.*

Plunker friednly ppl ur link is here [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/lYcLTRMEjOzuWUxLySTp?p=preview)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <h4>Filled column with w3-css</h4>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey">1</div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>

  </div>

  <h4>empty column with w3-css</h4>
  <h5>You cant keep your column empty??? You have to keep something in it. otherwise it want occupy any space. </h5>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <!-- Making first column emty   -->
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey"></div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>

  <h4>Filled column with Bootstrap css</h4>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">12123</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
  </div>

  <h4>empty column with Bootstrap css</h4>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this
`<div class="w3-col m4 w3-container"></div>`

`w3-container` will create an empty table including `padding`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>

  <h4>Filled column</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey">1</div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>
  
  <h4>empty column</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey"></div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>
  
  <h4>not empty column</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey"> </div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>

  <h4>Filled column with w3-container</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey w3-container">1</div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>

  <h4>empty column with w3-container</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey w3-container"></div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>
  
  <h4>not empty column with w3-container</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey w3-container"> </div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>
  
  <h4>empty column with w3-container no background color</h4>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-container"></div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For the benefit of the OP and others visiting this question, are you able to explain why this solution answers the question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:empty` selector and `:before` or `:after` to add some content to make the empty element use some space.

pseudo element are only CSS and cannot be selected nor accessed by javascript. it is not part of the DOM , it should be nothing to worry about.

---

- select **only** `:empty` elements `(no content, no white-space)`

  ```css
  .w3-row :empty:before {content:'fill it';visibility:hidden;}
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <title>W3.CSS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <body>

    <h4>Filled column with w3-css</h4>

    <div class="w3-row">
      <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey">1</div>
      <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>

    </div>

    <h4>empty column with w3-css</h4>
    <h5>You cant keep your column empty??? You have to keep something in it. otherwise it want occupy any space. </h5>
    <div class="w3-row">
      <!-- Making first column emty   -->
      <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey"></div>
      <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
    </div>

    <h4>Filled column with Bootstrap css</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">12123</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
    </div>

    <h4>empty column with Bootstrap css</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
  ```

---

- select **every** elements `:empty` and not

If your structure can have white space in your empty elements, it will be no longer efficient, it will not be seen as :empty. You can instead use the pseudo :after to each element to make sure all children will use some space.

```css
.w3-row > :after {content:'.';visibility:hidden;font-size:1px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <h4>Filled column with w3-css</h4>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey">1</div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>

  </div>

  <h4>empty column with w3-css</h4>
  <h5>You cant keep your column empty??? You have to keep something in it. otherwise it want occupy any space. </h5>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <!-- Making first column emty   -->
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-grey"> <!-- not :empty --></div>
    <div class="w3-col m8 w3-red">4</div>
  </div>

  <h4>Filled column with Bootstrap css</h4>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">12123</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
  </div>

  <h4>empty column with Bootstrap css</h4>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: upvoted, does bootstrap do the same for their columns? If no how do they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @GCyrillus is other approach but it may impact performance.

Bootstrap just use `min-height: 1px;` which prevents collapsing when column is empty.

```
position: relative;
//this min-height prevents collapsing when column is empty
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4"><h4></h4></div>
    <div class="w3-col m4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I add h4 in the col to create the space so add any html tag to create the space